# Is there any list of forbidden values for requestMappings in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a simple `REST/Flux` controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/deployment")
public class MyController{

    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, "application/zip"})
    public Mono<Status> uploadFiles(@RequestPart("file") FilePart file) {}

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<Status> list() {}

}
```

It worked fine until I added security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    private final CookieServerAuthenticationConverter cookieServerAuthenticationConverter;
    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final WebSecurityUnsecuredPaths webSecurityUnsecuredPaths;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, webSecurityUnsecuredPaths.getUnsecuredPathsMatchers())
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                                              oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()).bearerTokenConverter(cookieServerAuthenticationConverter)
                                                      .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec ->
                                           exceptionHandlingSpec
                                                   .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now `list`, that is `GET`, works fine, but `uploadFiles`, that is `POST`, stops working. I check this configuration with other controllers and everything looks fine. `GET`s work without auth and `POST`s need auth.

I made some experiments and finally when I change `/deployment` to `/uploadFile` everything starts working as expected.

So, now is my question:

Is there any list of „forbidden” values for `@RequestMapping` in Spring Security?

Comment: There are no forbidden values, by default Spring Security adds CSFR protection for POST/PUT/DELETE requests. If you don't include the token your request will be blocked.

Comment: Check you logs on the resource side, esp. with `org.springframework.security` set to debug and what the response looks like. POSTs and other REST verbs that can changed a resource are affected by other types of security.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added that. As I mentioned, it works with different mappings.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe nothing :(

Comment: As mentioned there are no forbidden values. Also you added what? That being said enable debug (or trace) logging for security and web and see what is happening.

Comment: There are no "forbidden" values, but there might be an overlapping controller from default configuration bound to `/deployment` that takes precedence over yours. Debug the handling of the problematic HTTP request and you'll find out the cause.

Comment: instead of us guessing here, please enable DEBUG logs and update your questions with the FULL logs when you are denied so that we can read the proper reason why the server rejects your call.